# Asus laptop with zero boot options

Tags: windows-7, boot

I just swapped out the SSD of my asus n56 vs4215h. It had a SSD and HDD instead of a HDD and DVD drive.

Now I placed back the HDD to the original spot and the DVD drive also back. (the ssd  is now in my gaming pc)

The laptop automaticly goes to bios. Don't get the chance to try boot options because there are none.

I checked some other topics but that didn't solve anything.

**Edit**

In the sata configuration both my HDD and DVD drive are listed.
When I go to boot options (with secure/fast boot on/off doesn't matter) there are no boot options.

**Edit 2**

[image]

it is like this picture but then with no boot options at all. (stole the picture from other question)

Comment: Are the devices listed in BIOS?

Comment: @Ramhound no they are not. Can it be that my HDD maybe is not 100% correct placed?

Comment: You are going to have to figure out the reason they are not even being detected in BIOS.  At this point you have not detectable devices that can even be used to boot from.  Check all connections.

Comment: Secure boot may need to be disabled, save settings on exit and reenter BIOS again. If that doesn't help, try the "fail safe" settings to see if it will recognize them after a restart.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated my question, they are both findable in the data configuration list. Now I plugged in my HDD to my main pc to install windows on it and check if it boots. Results in 50 mins

Comment: Make up your mind.  **I asked if they were detectable and you said they were not.**

Comment: @Ramhound I am not a pc wizard. I just found that sata configuration part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try resetting your BIOS to its default settings. Then, if that fails, Check all of the motherboards internal connections (like the HDD Wire). Below is a fix I've used for Windows 7:

A possible fix for this, I have encountered in the past. Due to the configuration of some computers, you must boot from a bootable windows install DVD (available here: http://heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/14-windows-7-direct-download-links ). Once booted into the installation disk, click repair, then try either the startup repair for n00bs, or try the command prompt. A few useful commands are: diskpart, chkdsk, and bootrec. for more info of these type " /?" after the initial command to see the commands help text.

I Sincerely Hope This Helps you out. Good Luck.

**EDIT:** It is also possible that your **cable** or Drive is broken. Also, installing an OS from another computer may cause harm to your HDD and is not Advisable.

Comment: Hmm, I read that edit to late. but the installing from other pc didn't work. Bios is reset to factory settings. When I go to data configuration in my bios it shows nicely my HDD/DVD but when I go to boot options there are none. I can't repair my windows because it won't allow me to boot from HDD/DVD or external DVD. Can try USB stick but don't expect much from that. Still many thanks for the help and time

Comment: data configuration is sata configuration* my auto correct changed that.

Comment: it is fixed by turning secure boot of and CSM on :)